# Run Testcontainers on Google Cloud Build

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, testcontainers

What is the best practice when you run Spring Boot Tests that depend on Testcontainers on Google Cloud Build?
Currently we have the following setup (unrelevant steps ommited):

```
steps:
# Git
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args: ['-c', 'http.sslVerify=false', 'clone', '<my source repository>',
         '--branch', 'my-tag', '--single-branch']
# Build
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['package', '-DskipTests=true']
  dir: src-dir
```

We have added some tests that use Testcontainers, and we want to enable the tests for the build on the cloud, but to run them on the cloud we need a cloud builder that have both Maven and docker.
I can't run the tests, on different step, separately from the build, as far as I know.
Is there a cloud builder that combines maven and docker or the only way is to create a custom one?

Thanks!

Comment: I configured Google Cloud Build to use the git repository and the cloudbuild.yml is even more simple. Also, I used maven wrapper. https://github.com/eddumelendez/testcontainers-samples/blob/main/cloudbuild.yaml